# adding controls dependent on sql table?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, dynamic

Hello all I'm working on a little project where I'm adding controls to a page based on a SQL table of questions, this table will grow overtime. I just wanted to share the code and see if there was any better way or if any of the experts could chime in and give me any insight on future problems.  Here is the code:

```
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            SqlParameter[] paramz = new SqlParameter[1];
            paramz[0] = new SqlParameter("@c_id", 1);

            dt = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataTable(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sql"].ToString(), CommandType.StoredProcedure, "get_Questions", paramz);
            clinicName.Text = "<b>" + dt.Rows[0]["Clinic Name"].ToString();

            for(int row = 0; row <= dt.Rows.Count; row++)
            {
                if (row == dt.Rows.Count) //if we're on the last question put a break for spacing(this could be fixed with styling)
                {
                    Literal alit = new Literal();
                    alit.Text = "<br/>";
                    questionsPanel.Controls.Add(alit);
                }
                else
                {
                    addQuestion(dt.Rows[row], row);
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            Response.Write(err.Message);
        }

    }

    private void addQuestion(DataRow row, int i)
    {
        Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.Text = row["question"].ToString();
        questionsPanel.Controls.Add(lbl);

        Literal lit = new Literal();
        lit.Text = "<br/>";
        questionsPanel.Controls.Add(lit);

        TextBox txt = new TextBox();
        txt.ID = "txt" + i.ToString();
        questionsPanel.Controls.Add(txt);

        Literal lit2 = new Literal();
        lit2.Text = "<br/>";
        questionsPanel.Controls.Add(lit2);

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a Repeater control:

ASPX Code:

```
<asp:Repeater id="repData" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label id="lblQuestion" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "question") %>' />
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox id="lblAnswer" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <br />
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Code behind:

```
// Populate repeater
SqlParameter[] paramz = new SqlParameter[1];
paramz[0] = new SqlParameter("@c_id", 1);
dt = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataTable(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sql"].ToString(), CommandType.StoredProcedure, "get_Questions", paramz);

repData.DataSource = dt;
repData.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

If the controls either use or contribute to ViewState, then you must ensure that the same controls are added to ViewState in the same order, on every post back. The order in which objects are added to ViewState depends on the order of the controls in the control tree.